# How to improve app performance when clicking hamburger menu items in UWP?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, uwp-xaml, uwp-navigation

I'm using Template 10 for the MVVM and the Hamburger menu in my UWP application. Normally from page to page navigation takes 2 to 3 secs. When App is in the background for more than 5 hours, then come back to the foreground, and page navigation takes 8 sec. How can I reduce the delay from page to page navigation?

XAML code for Menu Item:

````
```<Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo ClearHistory="True" x:Name="manifest" Selected="manifest_Selected" Unselected="manifest_Unselected" PageType="views:Manifest">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <BitmapIcon Width="30" Height="30" x:Name="manifesticon" Margin="10,20,0,0" UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/ic_menu_manifest.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="16,20,0,0" x:Name="manifesttext"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Text="Manifest" />
                </StackPanel>
   </Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo>```
````

CS code:

```
public void manifest_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        reportElement = new HamburgerButtonInfo();
        manifesticon.Foreground = (Brush)Application.Current.Resources["HeaderBackground"];
        manifesttext.Foreground = (Brush)Application.Current.Resources["HeaderBackground"];
        reportElement = manifest;
        if (report.IsEnabled)
        {
            report_Unselected(sender, e);
        }
    }

    public void manifest_Unselected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        manifesticon.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 229, 229, 229));
        manifesttext.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 229, 229, 229));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Normally from page to page navigation takes 2 to 3 secs.

You should not process synchronous call in page's constructer, it will block the ui thread to make navigation consume more time.

Currently, UWP contain native `NavigationView` that used to manage navigation, For more please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview).

And you could also make template app with template studio that could save more time to configure your app's base architecture. Fore more detail please refer [here](https://github.com/microsoft/windowsTemplateStudio).